# Getting attribute value according to another attribute

Tags: xpath

I have this xml:

```
<Forms>
<Form ID="5472" TemplateID="588" DocType="1" FileName="635073174134006854.pdf" HiulActType="1"/>
<Form ID="5472" TemplateID="2619" DocType="1" FileName="635073174134006854.pdf" HiulActType="1"/>
HiulDocCode="414" TimeStamp="2013-06-20-09_29_13_317421">
</Forms>
```

I want to get the attribute HiulActType of the form which has attribte TemplateID = 2619.

I tried:

```
`//Form[@TemplateID='2619']/@HiulActType/text()
```

Wont work.`

Comment: There is only the `text()` function superfluous.  Therefor `//Form[@TemplateID='2619']/@HiulActType` should do (if there is not  typo).  If not,  there is probably a namespace issue with your xml which you are hiding.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute nodes do not have text node children. Just drop the `/text()` from your path expression.

I'm seeing more and more people sprinkle `/text()` into their XPath expressions as a kind of magic fairy dust. It's almost always superfluous and often plain wrong. If you really want to force conversion of the result to a string rather than relying on automatic conversion, don't use `/text()`, use the `string()` function.